# Dataflow 2.1.0 streaming application is not cleaning temp folders

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

We have a dataflow application which reads from Pub/Sub, windows into fixed-size 1-minute duration windows and writes the raw messages to GCS with 10 shards. Our application has been running for 10 days now and it has created a .temp-beam-2017**** folder. There are about 6200 files under it and the count is growing every day.

My understanding is data flow will move the temp files to the specified output folder after the write is complete.

Could you please suggest what can be done in this case ? Each of these files are about 100MB.

```
inputCollection.apply("Windowing",
            Window.<String>into(FixedWindows.of(ONE_MINUTE))
                  .triggering(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                                .plusDelayOf(ONE_MINUTE))
                  .withAllowedLateness(ONE_HOUR)
                  .discardingFiredPanes()
                  )

    //Writing to GCS
                .apply(TextIO.write()
                            .withWindowedWrites()
                            .withNumShards(10)
                            .to(options.getOutputPath())
                            .withFilenamePolicy(
                                    new 
WindowedFileNames(options.getOutputPath())));
```

[image: When a file is copied::::::::]

[image: File is not copied]

Comment: Is the pipeline also generating the proper expected output files, or does it just keep accumulating temporary files but producing no expected output? Can you give a job ID?

Comment: Job id is 2017-10-23_12_29_09-11538967430775949506. It is writing output files. But, I am using fixed window of 1 minute with 10 shards. It is supposed to write 10 files per minute. That should be 14400 files per day. we are having only around ~13900 files per day. Some files are not being moved to output folder. Now, there are around 7000 files in temp folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discrepancy between 14400 and 13900 is most likely because your pipeline didn't get any data whose event time falls into a particular window and shard. When writing a windowed collection, we don't create empty files for "missing" windows, because in general, it is not possible to know which windows are "missing": it is, in theory, pretty clear for fixed or sliding windows, but not so for custom windowing functions or sessions etc. Moreover, assignment of shards is random, so it is possible that for a particular window very few data arrived, and then there's a pretty good chance that some of the 10 shards didn't get any of it.

As for why the temporary files are being left over: it seems that the pipeline is occasionally seeing exceptions when writing the files to GCS. The leftover files are "zombies" from those failed attempts to write data. We currently don't do a good job of cleaning up such files automatically in streaming mode (in batch, it is safe to delete the entire temporary directory when the pipeline is done, but in streaming we can't do that, and we delete only the individual files being renamed to their final location), but it should be safe for you to delete old temp files in that directory.

I've filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3145 to improve the latter.

Comment: Thank you @jkff. I am going to take some old files from temp folder and validate if they are written to our output folder. I will update here soon.

Comment: I took a sample file from the temp folder. This file was last modified on 11/02/2017, 05:55 AM under temp. I took few sample records if they were present in my final output. I cannot see those records in my final output location.

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Is the name of that temp file mentioned in the stackdriver logs? Is the computation between reading pubsub and writing to files deterministic?

Comment: I cannot find temp file name mentioned in stackdriver logs. This is the file name 00762dcc-eac0-469a-91ba-4ec1bc1a15e9. There is no computation between pubsub and writing files. I read from pub/sub, window into fixed duration of 1 minute and write to GCS.

Comment: any suggestions on what should I do ?

Comment: OK, to clarify: the file 00762dcc-eac0-469a-91ba-4ec1bc1a15e9 was left over in the temp directory; the name of this file is not mentioned in Stackdriver logs; you manually inspected the file and you are sure that the records contained in it are absent from your final output? (how are you verifying that these records are absent in final output, by the way?) If so, this is very worrying and does not match any existing issue I'm aware of. I will send a PR to improve the debugging information, because for now this is all I can think of doing.

Comment: See https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4103 . You might consider patching it in and seeing whether it helps debug the issue.

Comment: how are you verifying that these records are absent in final output, by the way? -- The temp file I took was last modified on 11/02/2017 5:55 AM. I took few sample records from temp file. Each record is a JSON and it has timestamp variable generated by other system. Time stamp in JSON is around 5:46 AM. That confirms that message arrived sometime between 5:46AM to 5:55AM. My output files will be written in hh-mm-shardNum format according to my fileNamePolicy. So I validated against all files between 5AM to 8AM of 11/02/2017.

Comment: I will try to debug with the patch you gave. Thank you @jkff.

Comment: @jkff-- I ran our application with the patch you gave. Looks like it is not copying all the files. I am updating question with the screenshots. Not all files are being copied to output folder. Both screen shots were taken at the same time.

Comment: OK that looks very worrying, I'll take a close look soon.

Comment: I'm investigating 2017-11-10_05_33_49-16312466580471084135 from your screenshot.

Comment: From what I understand, it does appear to be a bug that can happen when writing windowed data using WriteFiles with certain kinds of triggers. I'm going to file a JIRA and we'll further investigate and fix this at highest priority. Meanwhile try configuring the pipeline to never drop late data, e.g. wrap your trigger in a Repeatedly.forever() and set allowed lateness to infinity. So far it seems that the pipeline propagates the triggering of your input to the copying of output files themselves, and since yours is a fire-once trigger, in some racy cases it gives up after copying 1 file.

Comment: Thank you @jkff.  I will try that. Please let me know if I can help with some testing etc. as you fix this.

Comment: Thanks. I think at this moment the best help would be to check whether your pipeline works well with the suggested workarounds.

Comment: @rhg the trigger you set is a lossy trigger. Since you did not set Repeatedy, this trigger will fire the the first minute (in processing time) worth of data for the window, and then throw away the remaining data. Is this the trigger you meant to set?

Comment: @ReuvenLax i have fixed window of 1 minute duration. I want to collect that 1 minute worth of data and write to GCS. I wanted to allow late data for 1 hour.  I am going to try the work arounds and update you here.

Comment: @jkff looks like wrapping trigger with repeatedly.forever() and having very large allowLateness is working. It is clearing temp files immediately. I have been running my application for few hours now. I will test it for one more day and update you.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad the workaround worked. Regarding what @ReuvenLax said: windowing is in "event time" rather than "processing time" - so currently your pipeline is specifying "for each event-time window, collect data for 1 minute of processing time since the first arrival of an element whose event-time timestamp maps into this window". This definitely can have very weird behavior if your data can be considerably out of order.

Comment: @rhg what semantics did you want? do you want to window by "event time" (e.g. parsing a timestamp out of the input) or by "processing time" (based on when the pipeline first sees the data). In either case, what you've written here is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: @ReuvenLax -- I do not want to parse timestamp out of my input. My understanding is Pub/Sub automatically assigns timestamp to each element and windowing happens based on that timestamp. My over all requirement is to read everything that is published to pub/sub and write to GCS. It is ok if few records that have timestamps inside my input as t1 are written to the output file of t2. As long as everything is written to GCS we are fine. However, please suggest if you think we need to make any changes to our window/trigger.

Comment: @jkff -- With new fix, do I still need to have Repeatedly.forever() ? I removed "Repeatedly" and used my old trigger. I see some files are not being copied. Sample file name: gs://hd-personalization-stage/.temp-beam-2017-11-318_14-31-31-0/32012c88-1179-482c-9f49-1ba1d3ebe156

Comment: @rhg Do you mean that you tried patching in PR #4124 and you're still seeing files not being copied? Could you give a Dataflow job ID to investigate that, if so? For the trigger: I'm not sure why you need a custom trigger at all - doesn't simple fixed windowing with default trigger not do what you want? You probably do need a Repeatedly.forever() and we're considering completely removing "fire-once" triggers due to their error-proneness.

Comment: As-is, your trigger says not only "for each event-time window, collect data for 1 minute of processing time since the first arrival of an element whose event-time timestamp maps into this window" but also "AND silently drop all future data whose event time maps into this window"

Comment: @jkff this is my job id:: 2017-11-14_06_31_36-14490092676559913663. yes, I was planning to remove trigger. Just Fixed window should be enough for our use case.

Comment: @rhg I don't see file 32012c88-1179-48‌​2c-9f49-1ba1d3ebe156 mentioned in the Stackdriver logs of job 2017-11-14_06_31_36-14490092676559913663, are you sure this is the right job? Also, can you explicitly confirm what SDK version are you using: if you built your own SDK from PR #4124, then what is the exact git commit hash from which you're building? And are you confident that your program is using the correct SDK jar rather than something from Maven cache for example?

Comment: The fix PR has been submitted and will be cherrypicked into 2.2.0.

Comment: @jkff it is working. Like you said it was the maven cache. Thank you for all the quick responses. Now temp files are not being accumulated at all. So  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3145 is also resolved with this ? Roughly when do you think 2.2.0 would be in available ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159096/discussion-between-rhg-and-jkff).